# Conditionally format multiple cells using multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to apply conditional formatting to this sheet: 
[image: Excel Sheet]

`AM` Needs to be:

- equal to or less than `3` (red)
- equal to `4` (pink)
- equal to or greater than `5` (green)

`PM` Needs to be:

- equal to or less than `4` (red)
- equal to `5` (pink)
- equal to or greater than `6` (green)

Both the cell in column `B` containing the number as well as the cell in column `A` containing the `AM` and `PM` values both need to be highlighted.

For example

`| PM | 5 |` (both pink)
`| AM | 5 |` (both green)

What formula should I use in order to do that?

Comment: Welcome to [Super User](https://superuser.com/ "https://superuser.com/"). Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask "https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask") then edit your question.   Pay particular attention to the section titled [Search, and research](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Search%2C%20and%20research)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You asked "what formula?" - you've essentially answered your own question already ... Go to Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules, and add a new rule for each condition that you've described above (ie. AM/PM for the "A" column, and your greater than/less than rules for the "B" column).  If you think you've configured the rules in the correct way, but the formatting is not as you expect, then you can add the rule formulas into your question so that others can assist you with where you might have gone astray

Answer (score 0):

Create Conditional Formatting rule for each column.

For example:  *AM equal to or less than 3 (red)*

```
=AND(A1="AM",B1<=3)
```

[image]